# Undefined error in PHP

Tags: php

I've tried using following htmlentities for a text box and I got the following undefined variable error inside the textbox. I've tried changing my php to `<?= htmlentities [$_POST['invo_val'] ?>` but still get the same message. Any idea where I have gone wrong?

```
<td><input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php htmlentities($_POST['invc_no']) ?>"></td>
```

and the error says : `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: invc_no in <b>E:\xampp\htdocs\ss\docs\addInvo.php</b> on line <b>394</b><br />`

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a POST request or `invo_val` is not passed if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try do not get data from unset post

```
$invc_no = isset($_POST['invc_no']) ? $_POST['invc_no'] : '';

<td><input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php htmlentities($invc_no) ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP gives this notice when you try to access a variable that is not defined.

You should check if the variable exists first (using `isset`) before you use it.

For example:

```
<?php $value = isset($_POST['invc_no']) ? htmlentities($_POST['invc_no']) : ''; ?>

<td><input type="text" id="invc_no" name="invc_no" size="15" class="colr" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check first that the post variable is set or not. Use below code:

```
if(isset($_POST['invc_no'])
{
$inv_no=$_POST['invc_no'];
}
else
{
$inv_no='';
}
```

and now use this `$inv_no` into your code

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to suppress the *Notice* with the error control operator: [@](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

```
<?= @$_POST['invc_no']; ?>
```